# How to derive from a variadic template class in C++

Tags: c++, c++11, inheritance, variadic-templates, stdtuple

I have variadic template class which is just a wrapper for std::tuple :

```
template <typename ... Child>
class Tpl
{
public:
    Tpl() {}
    Tpl(Child ...args) : child(args...)
    {}

    template <typename T>
    T& Get()
    {
        return std::get<T>(child);
    }

    template <typename T>
    const T& GetConst()
    {
        return std::get<T>(child);
    }
private:
    std::tuple<Child ...> child;
};
```

How do I correctly derive a class from `Tpl`?

```
template <typename... Ts>
class SomeObject : public Tpl<Ts...>
{
public:
    SomeObject(/*Types ... args*/) /*: child(args...)*/
    {

    }
private:
    int num;        
};
```

The compiler (VS14 CTP 6) message just tells me:

```
syntax error: missing ',' before '<' in the line: class SomeObject: public Tpl<Ts...>
```

Comment: That looks correct to me, what compiler and version are you using? (I took the liberty of fixing `SomeObject`'s constructor name, judging from the error message that wasn't the cause of the error)

Comment: `DbgGameObject` eh? So you're not posting the code you're testing. Test the MCVE then post the error message as it appears _for that MCVE_.

Comment: There is no VS14 CTP 6.

Comment: There is CTP 6: http://www.visualstudio.com/news/vs2015-vs#ctp6

Comment: @Fabian: That's VS15 CTP 6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[The code is fine](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/10f00aaeb119738c).**

You didn't tell us what compiler (inc. its version) you're using, but presumably it has limited/no support for variadic templates or is buggy in this regard. Consider upgrading it or switching to something else entirely. GCC and Clang are both good.

Comment: I'm using the lastest version of Visual Studio 2015. I can't switch the compiler

Comment: Then you cannot do what you want unless you find a workaround or wait until MS releases a new version with this bug fixed.

Comment: After a restart, a clean and rebuild it compiled with no erros. Sorry for wasting your time with that nonsens -_-

Comment: @Fabian: Old code then.